# Regex in php excluding values

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have these lines of text **($text variable)**

```
CC 1,00
SS 1,00
PP 1,00
1,00
FF 1,00
```

now I would like to have only the numeric part of each line returned to me. But the important thing must be that I don't have to take lines that start with certain characters, like I would like to exclude "SS", "PP" and "FF".
So I would like it to return me only the values of "CC" and only the numeric ones without leading characters.

In the meantime I have done this but it doesn't seem to work

```
preg_match_all("/((?!.SS|.FF|.PP).*\d{1,2}[\,\.]{1}\d{1,2})\w+/", $text, $matches);
```

Unfortunately, I don't get the desired result, where am I wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your regex to this: `^(?!SS|FF|PP).*(\d{1,2}[,.]\d{1,2})`

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/SAivli/2

```
$re = '/^(?!SS|FF|PP).*(\d{1,2}[,.]\d{1,2})$/m';
$str = 'CC 1,00
SS 1,00
PP 1,00
1,00
FF 1,00';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
//Array ( [0] => Array ( 
//                        [0] => CC 1,00 
//                        [1] => 1,00 
//                      )
//         [1] => Array ( [0] => 1,00
//                        [1] => 1,00 
//                      )
//        )
```

This matches both the numbers that:

- begin with CC
- dont have any leading alpha characters

Answer (score 1):

You can anchor the negative lookahead to the start of the string, and omit the leading dots in `.SS` as it matches a single character.

You can also omit the `{1}` and the backslashes in `[\,\.]`

As there are no other characters in the examples besides spaces and 2 uppercase characters, you can change `.*` to match `[A-Z]{2}` followed by optional horizontal whitespace chars `\h*`

Omit the `\w+` at the end because there are no more word characters and the `+` expects at least a single char.

```
^(?!SS|FF|PP)[A-Z]{2}\h*\K\d{1,2}[,.]\d{1,2}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!SS|FF|PP)` Assert not any of the alternatives to the right
- `[A-Z]{2}` Match 2 uppercase chars
- `\h*\K` Match optional whitespace chars and forget what is matched so far
- `\d{1,2}[,.]\d{1,2}` Match 1-2 digits followed by either `.` or `,` and again 1-2 digits
- `$` End of string

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LM759p/1)

```
$re = '/^(?!SS|FF|PP)[A-Z]{2}\h*\K\d{1,2}[,.]\d{1,2}$/m';
$text = 'CC 1,00
SS 1,00
PP 1,00
1,00
FF 1,00';

preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,00
)
```